# Linq to Entities / Entity Framework delete exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, exception, linq-to-entities

I'm working on a WPF system which hooks onto an old legacy database using the Entity Framework. We hook onto a backup of the live data when debugging and an empty database to run tests against. I'm receiving the following error only when trying to delete from a backup of the live data.

This code:

```
License license = ReadLicense(id);
entities.DeleteObject(license);
entities.SaveChanges();
```

produces this SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'delete [dbo].[Product]
where ((([Group_ID] = @0) and ([Parent_ID] = @1)) and ([Prod_ID] = @2))',N'@0 nvarchar(32),@1 nvarchar(32),@2 nvarchar(32)',@0=N'someIdValue1',@1=N'someIdValue2',@2=N'someIdValue3'
```

which in turn produces this error:

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TrackDeletedProduct, Line 4.
Invalid object name 'DeletedRecords.dbo.Product_Deleted'.

If you change the generated SQL to a 'select' query it returns a row so, 'ReadLicense' is returning a valid entity. I can't really understand why this doesn't work, especially when it's only against live data. The 'License' entity is one of two inheriting from a base 'Product' entity.

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can see, it would appear as if your table `Product` has a trigger on it that will fire when you delete a row, and which calls that stored procedure `TrackDeletedProduct`.

That procedure will (just guessing here) try to copy the product entry to the `Product_Deleted` table in the `DeletedRecords` database, but fails on that - either that other database or the table don't seem to exist.

So I don't think this has really anything to do with ADO.NET Entity Framework or LINQ-to-Entities, but a lot with SQL Server - check your backend database configuration!

Marc

Comment: Thank you very much man, didnt think of table triggers. FYI the empty version of the db is created from a cut down version of the backup's creation script, i found that out since showing you're solution to my co-worker who did that. So the trigger simply wasn't in there. Rekon i should edit the tags?? Might help others more...

Comment: Glad I could help - I would leave the tags as they are - no problem.